# Adhesive for indoor fireplace veneer

Tags: fireplace

Ledgestone veneer 1 1/2 to 2 inch stone was added around a gas fireplace.  This installed directly on hardy backer board with Licote proline Premium adhesive.  My question is there ANY chance that the heat from the gas fireplace with break down the adhesive over time and stones will fall off the wall? thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/tds/PL_CA_PREM_tds.pdf) it can sustain 250 degree F with occasional exposure. It will be difficult to determine just how hot it gets at the glue layer, since the stone and backer board act as a heat sink, and what is on the surface of the stone, will not be the same at the glue layer.

Comment: there's surely no way it gets hotter than boiling water on the surface, that's dangerous as all get-out. Furthermore, most gas ones have a double-flue duct that doesn't touch the masonry.

Comment: That is all correct that you state about the flue but I picked up on this being the veneer that's part of the facade around the fireplace opening itself where the heat coming out from the top of the fireplace opening into the room gets quite hot.